# Unable to successfully deploy liferay portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

I have been following the tutorial in https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/writing-your-first-liferay-application and built the portlet for liferay as described. I have a working liferay environment and can add and remove all of the standard portlets.

When trying to push the porlet that I've made to the server I can see that it has correctly deployed to the server. See log below.

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/marc.thomas/Downloads/liferay/bundles/tomcat 7.0.62/webapps/guestbook-portlet
Mar 04, 2016 10:49:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 04, 2016 10:49:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /Users/marc.thomas/Downloads/liferay/bundles/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/guestbook-portlet has finished in 900 ms
Mar 04, 2016 10:49:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
```

I have put the full log and the code in my github account here: https://github.com/marcthomas2013/liferay-portlet

In this log there is no presence of liferay picking up the portlet and deploying it, even though it is deployed to tomcat.

I can't see what else I can check now. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your portlet plugin, copy the WAR file to Liferay's `deploy` folder (find it in `/Users/marc.thomas/Downloads/liferay/bundles/`). Liferay will take care of injecting some required components and deploy it to tomcat itself.

Just deploying the build result to an application server typically does not work (unless you specifically change the build process to include the injected features)

Correction: According to the log file you seem to have moved your installation after the initial install:

```
10:49:49,077 INFO [localhost-startStop-1][AutoDeployDir:139] Auto deploy scanner started for /Users/marc.thomas/Downloads/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6/deploy
```

That's where you need to drop your build result.